# LN Alicization - no appearance of Murderer/Assassin Tribe in battle?

Tags: sword-art-online

The Murderer's Tribe doesn't appear in the battle / make a contribution. They are non-existent in the diagrams displaying how both sides are positioned as well.

Is this something the author missed or did I miss something along the way?

It seems strange as each tribe is meant to contribute to the war effort in some way.

---

I've finished LN Vol. 17 and just noticed it. Judging from the plot, I don't find it likely they'll have a chance to appear later on either

Comment: Yeah they're strangely absent. You didn't miss anything. They don't appear in Vol. 18 either...